# Vertically centering a label in a HBox control with Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using a HBox as a container for a label and a textbox. I'd like for both of them to be vertically centered, but no matter how try that doesn't seem to end up happening:

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
  setScene(new Scene(new HBox(10) {
    setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10))

    getChildren.add(new Label("Text to find:") { setAlignment(Pos.CENTER) })
    getChildren.add(new TextField() { setMinWidth(300) })
  }))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)` on the `HBox`.

Comment: I was pretty sure I had already tried that. Seems like I didn't.